# Small proportion of true alternatives in the `qvalue` package.

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I'm trying to use `qvalue` package in `R` to work out the proportion of true alternative tests. However, when I use the package, I get $\pi_0$ (proportion of true nulls) to be  > 1, using a small $\lambda$ tuning parameter. Also, $\pi_0(\lambda)$ seems to decrease as $\lambda$ increases.

In my simulated dataset I have a very small proportion of true alternatives. (approx 0.001%)

Could this be the reason for the function giving incorrect output?

Would there be any way I can work out the true proportion of alternative tests?

Comment: Can you give us more details? What functions are you using in the `qvalue` package?

Comment: Do you have any $P$-values which are actually larger than your $\lambda$?

Answer (score 0):

Making no assumptions about anything else (because you haven't provided any additional details), the only reason why you would get a $\pi_0 > 1$ would be a $\lambda$ value which is too small.

Looking at the source code of `qvalue`, we can see that the `pi0est.R` function has the following code:

https://github.com/jdstorey/qvalue/blob/master/R/pi0est.R

```
 # Determines pi0
  if (ll == 1) {
    pi0 <- mean(p >= lambda)/(1 - lambda)
    pi0.lambda <- pi0
    pi0 <- min(pi0, 1)
    pi0Smooth <- NULL
```

Given `ll` is length of $\lambda$, `lambda` is your $\lambda$ value, and `p` is the vector of $P$-values.

Assuming that you have a `l` of length 1, the $\pi_0$ is estimated to be

$$ \frac{\text{mean of all P values larger than } \lambda}{1-\lambda}$$

It is then redefined as the minimum between the above value and 1, so if the above quantity is larger than 1, it is reported as $\geq 1$.

I would encourage you to perhaps rethink your $\lambda$ selection or look into alternate methods for estimating $\pi_0$. [Storey's 2011 paper](http://genomine.org/papers/Storey_FDR_2011.pdf) accompanying the `qvalue` package provides a good intro and references. Additionally, full code for the `qvalue` package is found [here](https://github.com/jdstorey/qvalue).

Comment: Thanks Chris. This is the output i get. pi0 which is supposed to be a proortion results in a value>1 for small lambda.
> qvalue(p=pvalue3)$lambda
 [1] 0.05 0.10 0.15 0.20 0.25 0.30 0.35 0.40 0.45 0.50 0.55 0.60 0.65 0.70 0.75 0.80 0.85 0.90 0.95
> qvalue(p=pvalue3)$pi0.lambda
 [1] 1.0024455 1.0044893 1.0110517 1.0126263 1.0154882 1.0152958 1.0178710 1.0168350 1.0159780 1.0113131 1.0181818 1.0196970 1.0112554 1.0235690 1.0020202
[16] 0.9707071 0.9791246 0.9474747 0.9737374
> qvalue(p=pvalue3)$pi0
[1] 0.9675674

Comment: Sorry, just so we're on the same page, $\pi_0$ is the proportion of true nulls (i.e. no association), rather than the proportion of true associations, which it seems like you're saying up above. So your model is estimating that ~ 97% of your tests are definitely true null associations. The above output doesn't look unreasonable to me, if it reports a $q$-value larger than 1, it just means that its 1.